# JavaScript applying only to one div

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs with same class.

```
<div class="html-code"></div>
<div class="html-code"></div>
```

I added JavaScript to the class.
I took variable like this.

```
var html = document.getElementsByClassName("html-code")[0];
```

It is so strange that the JavaScript I functioned on the variable html is applying only to the first div but not second.
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getElementByClassName()` will give collection of elements with matched classnames

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements that match the selector, so in this case all elements with the class name `html-code`.  Then, the `[0]` gets the first element in that collection.  So that code gets the first matching element.  If you changed it to `[1]` it would get the second, and so on.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are u missing` . ` Before index?

Comment: I want the function to apply for both the divs

Comment: What function?  Post what you're trying to do with the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out this way:

```js
var html = document.getElementsByClassName("html-code");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(html, function(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});
```

```css
.html-code {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="html-code"></div>
<div class="html-code"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the index [0] from the end to select all divs, like this.

```
var html = document.getElementsByClassName("html-code");
```

or use a loop like this:

```js
var html = document.getElementsByClassName("html-code");

for (i in html) {
  html[i].innerHTML = "div " + i;
}
```

```html
<div class="html-code"></div>
<div class="html-code"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question, when you do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("html-code");
```

The response is a **array-like object** called [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) then

```
document.getElementsByClassName("html-code")[0]//<-- first element

document.getElementsByClassName("html-code")[1]//<-- second element
```

Because the class `html-code` has two matches in this case.

To iterate over the elements you can't use the array methods like `.map()` or `filter()` you should use methods used for objects:

`for(var element in object) {//code}`

or the generic:

`for(let i; i<object.length;i++){//code}`

and methods using the [Object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), like:

```
var keys = Object.keys(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I finally solved the problem by adding two variables and also two functions.

```
var html = document.getElementsByClassName("html- 
code")[0];

html.onclick = function() {
// My JavaScript function
}

var html = document.getElementsByClassName("html- 
code")[1];

html.onclick = function() {
// Same function as above
}
```

This is working for me.
I understood that if there are two divs with same class, we have to add two functions.